# Is there a way to differentiate the "draw a polygon" and "draw a marker" events with the "adddrawtoolbar" function in Rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

Thanks to the `leaflet.extras` package it is easy to draw a polygon and/or a marker on a leaflet map as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Once clicked on those buttons it is possible to trigger an event like this:

```
observeEvent(input$map_draw_new_feature, { random_function() })
```

However I'm looking for a way to differentiate the observeEvent according if the user draw a polygon or a marker on the leaflet map. Something like that for instance:

```
observeEvent(input$map_draw_new_polygon, { random_function() })
observeEvent(input$map_draw_new_marker, { random_function() })
```

Is there a way to do such thing or there is no way to detect the feature type selected by the user before drawing it on the map ?!

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but did you see that `leaflet.extras`'s author [doesn't recommend](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras#readme) using this package? You should use [`leafpm`](https://github.com/r-spatial/leafpm) instead, which is supported by r-spatial

Comment: I had no idea 'leaflet.extras' had become obsolete, thanks for the tips @bretauv. 
(for those who may be looking at my question, I'm still looking for an answer !)